# Excercise in character counting (bash)

Tags: bash, variable, input

I have the following script which counts characters in user input:

```
    echo -n "Type text: ";
    read mystring;
    echo -n $mystring | wc -m;
```

Without the "-n" in the last line, the character count would be wrong because it would also include the newline character put there by echo (so the count for e.g. "abc" would be 4 instead of 3.)

For the sake of practice I now want to do this correction in a more complicated way. The general idea is like this:

```
     var=$($mystring | wc -m);
     echo -n "Type text: ";
     read mystring;
     echo $(( $var - 1 ));
```

So the character count of user input becomes $var and then I subtract 1 from $var. How do I make it work?

Comment: `read string <<<"abcd"; printf 'String is %d chars long\n' "${#string}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script does not work for several reasons:

- You start by initializing `var` to be equal to the output of running the command `| wc -m` because `mystring` is at this point null.
- Even if it were not null, it would attempt to run its contents as a command, and send that output into `wc`.

You have to A> do things in the right order, and ii.> do the correct things:

```
read -p "Type something > " mystring
var="$( wc -m <<< "$foo" )"
echo $(($var-1))
```

Comment: thank you, that solved it! I had already tried putting the var line after read, but as I didn't construct it correctly, of course it didn't work. I forgot to put the whole thing in quotes, add echo, and put $mystring in quotes also!

Comment: That won't work properly if `$mystring` is `-nene` for instance. You can't use `echo` for arbitrary data. Or if `$IFS` contains digits arithmetic expansions should also be quoted.

Comment: It also won't work properly if what the user enters starts or ends with blanks or contains backslashes.

Comment: Revised to use `<<<` which seems to play nice with strings starting with hyphens (`wc -m <<< "-nene"`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the number of characters in what the user entered up to but not including the newline character, then it should be:

```
#! /bin/sh -
printf 'Type text: '
IFS= read -r userInput
length=$(printf %s "$userInput" | wc -m)
# or:
length=${#userInput}
```

If you want to include the newline character that the user possibly entered, then:

```
#! /bin/sh -
printf 'Type text: '
IFS= read -r userInput && userInput="$userInput
"
length=$(printf %s "$userInput" | wc -m)
# or:
length=${#userInput}
```

`read` will typically return *true* if a full line was input (the newline character is present) which is why we append one if `read` was successful.

Note that in most shell implementations (`zsh` being the exception), it won't work properly if the user enters a NUL (aka `^@`) character.

To work around that, you could do:

```
printf 'Type text: '
length=$(line | wc -m)
```

instead. Or:

```
length=$(line | tr -d '\n' | wc -m)
# or
length=$(($(line | wc -m) - 1)) # as line always includes a newline on
                                # output even if one was not provided on
                                # input.
```

if you don't want to count the newline.

The behaviour will vary as well if the user manages to enter bytes that don't form part of valid characters. You'll also find some `sh` implementations whose `${#var}` doesn't work properly with multi-byte characters (would return the length in bytes instead of characters).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have to study it a bit to understand. For now I just wanted to understand how to do the var construction, which was the main cause that it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr " $mystring" : '.*' - 1
```

will return the length of the contents of the shell variable `mystring`

Comment: See also `expr + "$mystring" : '.*'` with GNU `expr`.

Comment: Strictly speaking that counts the number of characters at the start of `$mystring`. For instance in a UTF-8 locale (on a GNU system at least) `expr $'foo\200bar' : '.*'` would return 3 (length of `foo`, `\200` is not a character). While `printf 'foo\200bar' | wc -m` would return 6 (and GNU `expr length $'foo\200bar'` returns 7)

Answer (score 0):

In bash you'd use

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p 'Type text: ' userInput
printf 'Your input was %d chars long\n' "${#userInput}"
```

The string count can be retrieved by `${#var}`. Using `wc` is in this case unnecessary

Comment: thanks, but I purposely wanted to use wc in order to understand the construction of the var line

Comment: Note that `read` without `IFS=` and without `-r` doesn't store the input exactly as typed into `$userInput`.